# html tags not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i have a form and when i append another field to it i cant use this in my other function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".registerNums").click(function(){
              $("#hello").append('<input type="button" value="register" class="inputMems">');
          });
          $(".inputMems").click(function(){
             alert("hi")
         });
       });
   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <form>
        <div id="hello"></div>
        <input type="button" value="register mems" class="registerNums">
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

look my inputMems button doesnt work : http://jsfiddle.net/Yelesee/3uecqLxn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".registerNums").click(function(){
        $("#hello").append('<input type="button" value="register" class="inputMems">');
    });
    $("#hello").on('click','.inputMems',function(){console.log("hi");});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<form>
<div id="hello"></div>

<input type="button" value="register mems" class="registerNums">
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

To bind events in dynamic content you need to use

```
$(parent_selector).on(event, selector, callback);
```

So, essentially it adds the event to the parent element and checks the `e.target` and fires the event if it matches your selector.

So, in your case you can use,

```
$('#hello').on('click', '.inputMems', function(){
    ///do here
});
```

One more thing you can do is attaching the event listener **AFTER** the new dom has been created.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dynamically adding the DOM element with reference to **id** = **hello**,
The click() wont work. It will work for the elements that already exist. It won't get bound to elements created dynamically. To do that, you'll have to create a "delegated" binding by using on().

Replace your click event

```
 $(".inputMems").click(function(){
     alert("hi")
 });
```

to this!

```
 $("#hello").on("click", "input.inputMems", function(){
   alert("Here u go!");
 });
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3uecqLxn/24/)

Comment: can you write it in jsfiddle?

Comment: @AbolfazlEbadi if it solves your issue then please select the answer so that it will be helpful for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other answers you can define the click handler when you create the element. Although i do recommend to use `.on('click', function(){});`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".registerNums").click(function() {
    var newInput = $('<input type="button" value="register" class="inputMems">');
    newInput.click(function() {
      alert("hi")
    });
    $("#hello").append(newInput);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form>
    <div id="hello"></div>

    <input type="button" value="register mems" class="registerNums">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have insert

```
$(".inputMems").click(function(){
alert("hi")
});
```

inside `$(".registerNums").click(function(){
        $("#hello").append('<input type="button" value="register" class="inputMems">');
    });`
.

It should be like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".registerNums").click(function(){
    $("#hello").html('<input type="button" value="register" class="inputMems">');
    $(".inputMems").click(function(){
    alert("hi");
});
});
```

});